# cd to variable not working in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have following variables

```
$a=/opt
$b=var
$c=usr
$path=/$a/$b/$c/man
```

when I do cd $path it says no such file or directory.

but this path actually exist /opt/var/usr/man .. any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you try `echo $path`. because you don't have / mentioned in the variable. its not working.

Comment: No it does not work

Comment: try this. `echo $a$b$c`

Comment: Are we even sure that path exists?  Try `ls -ld /opt/var/usr/man`.

Comment: 1. `$path=/$a/$b/$c/man` doesn't do what you think it does. Try `path=test;$path=123` and see what error message it prints. 2. Why aren't you [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting) your parameter expansions?

Comment: @PM2Ring:  I'm doubting your mind reading skills on this.  I don't think OP knows `$PATH`.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I said nothing about `PATH` or `$PATH`. I used lower-case `$path` in my example because that's what the OP used.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is a bad syntax in variable assignments.

```
$a=/opt
$b=var
$c=usr
$path=/$a/$b/$c/man
```

..  will never work since variable assignments must not be preceded by `$`.

You should instead do it as follows:

```
a=opt
b=var
c=usr
dir=/$a/$b/$c/man
cd $dir
```

Note that I changed the final variable name as it is a bad idea to use two variables with the same name but in a different case as it can be confusing.  (`PATH` being a very important environment variable)

Answer (score -2):

If you try this `echo $a$b$c` you will get this

```
[root@centseven ~]# echo $a$b$c
/optvarusr
```

So this is not a a execute.

Your last variable should be `path=/$a$b$c/man`

Change your variable to the below

```
$a=/opt
$b=/var
$c=/usr
```

Then try `echo $path` it works for me

```
[root@centseven ~]# echo $path
/opt/var/usr/man
```

Comment: There are 2 or 3 mistakes in this, but I will wait some clarifications from OP before I post my answer.

Comment: I think OP haven't tried `echo $path` he is trying `cd $path`.

Comment: I tried both echo $path and cd $path none of them worked .. When I do echo $path it shows the correct path /opt/var/usr/man  but My requriment is I need to do inside that directory thats why i am trying to cd command

Comment: @Manish:  `echo $path` can not fail so if you say it didn't work, you have to say what it did.

Comment: @Manish:  Can you please show me the output of `ls -ld /opt/var/usr/man`?

Comment: one min let me capture that

Comment: ls -ld /opt/var/usr/man
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan  6 07:31 /opt/var/usr/man

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51272/discussion-between-manish-and-julie-pelletier).